# CSS: Can I query for actual device width in inches and if not, how do I query for all mobile devices as of 2015?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

In my CSS, I'm using `@media (max-width: 10in)` to query for mobile devices. However, that query doesn't work on e.g. a Nexus 10 or an Ipad.
I believe this is because the the device width is determined based on some standardized DPI which is not the true DPI?

So how can I target the *actual* device width in inches using CSS' media-queries?

And if that doesn't work, how can I target *all* mobile devices from an old Galaxy Mini over Iphone 6 Plus and the Ipad/Nexus 10 without affecting any desktop monitors from 17" 800x600 and upwards?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: A common breakpoint seems to be 1024px, which works fine for everything but the Nexus 10; which has a resolution of 1280px (Same as a lot of Desktop Monitors). Would it be bad practice to use 1024px and delivering the Desktop-style to tablets with such high resolutions?

And please give reason if you consider my question bad enough to down-vote.

EDIT 2:
I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` for Physical Units to work properly in styling. That doesn't affect the Media Queries, though.

Comment: Don't design for devices...the list is never-ending and always changing. Put your breakpoints whenever you need them...that might be 1234p or 965px...whatever. when the design breaks becuase the screen is too small...add another breakpoint.

Comment: So I should be okay with mobile devices with resolutions bigger than my breakpoint to get the desktop version?

Answer (score 1):

To target an ipad, or any other device for that matter,  (there are several different kinds out there)  you would need to specify a min-width as well as a max-width. Also, you may want to specify the potrait and landscape widths as well.Try one of the following in your css for the iPad:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

The `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  2` targets retina devices.  By googling you can actually find out the exact min & max widths that you need for specific devices.

Hope this helps.